# Multiple Instances of a Worker Role on Azure Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

How can i start multiple instances of a worker role in Azure Emulator for debugging in VS 2012?

Comment: More details please. Looking at your question, just increase the instance count from 1 to whatever in the worker role project properties. Now when you debug your cloud service project, those many worker role instances will be spinned off.

Comment: i think thats what i need to do.

Comment: @GauravMantri: Is that really supported on Emulator?

Comment: @sharptooth It sure does. Please see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n4d1W.png

Comment: The full emulator supports multiple instances, but I think the new express emulator that shipped with SDK 2.1 only supports single instance for each role. Could it be that they have the express emulator selected?